# What's the difference between Task.Run and JoinableTaskFactory.Run?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Supposing I have an async method/a task that I need to invoke from a non-async method, and I could do this using the JoinableTaskFactory, something like this:

```
var jtf = new JoinableTaskFactory(new JoinableTaskContext());
var serviceResponse = jtf.Run(async () =>  await _service.UpdateSomethingAsync(requestObject));
```

How is it different from this:

```
var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await _service.UpdateSomethingAsync(requestObject));
var serviceResponse = task.Result;
```

Or this:

```
ServiceResponse serviceResponse = null;

var task = Task.Run(async () => serviceResponse = await _service.UpdateSomethingAsync(requestObject));
Task.WaitAll(task);
```

If I have a task that I need to execute from a non async method, what's actually the best way to do this, as there are quite a few options available?

Comment: `JoinableTaskFactory` provides an API surface specialized for programming Visual Studio features. Unless you're doing that, I wouldn't want to take a dependency on it.

Comment: It's actually flagged as a warning if I use Task.Run and then Wait on the new task to complete execution.
If I use Task.WaitAll on the new task created using Task.Run, I don't get this warning:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD002.md

Why does MS make this JoinableTaskFactory if we're not supposed to be using it? Quite curious.

Comment: The diagnostic you linked has nothing to do with `JoinableTaskFactory`. It is warning you to use `async`/`await`/`Task` correctly. You should use `await Task.WhenAll`. Using `WaitAll` blocks and should be avoided.

Comment: What's the real problem? `JoinableTaskFactory` requires installing the Visual Studio SDK (and probably running inside VS). The other two snippets waste a thread by blocking. If you don't want to block use `await _service.UpdateSomethingAsync(requestObject)` *only*. If you do want to block, then 1) bad idea, 2) Use `.Result` on the task you already have :`_service.UpdateSomethingAsync(requestObject).Result`

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(task);` is quirky itself. There's only one task. You can use `Task.Wait()` or `Task.Result`

Comment: @Aluan, yes, the warning I mentioned has nothing to do with the JoinableTaskFactory, it shows when using var task = Task.Run(); task.Wait(); If Task.WaitAll doesn't show this warning and it to be avoided, what do you think is the best way to call an async method from a non-async method? JoinableTaskFactory looked like a straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @lex87 sorry, I misunderstood your last comment. Running a task returning method synchronously is something which should be avoided. Not only does it introduce the possibility of deadlocks, it also changes exception propagation in surprising ways. If you absolutely must invoke at synchronously you should use the `GetAwaiter` extension method to normalize exception propagation. There's a lot of other problems though. Some guidance: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058

Comment: @Aluan, with so many ways to do multithreading it seemed like a good idea to use the JoinableTaskFactory, as I found the approach to be more "fluid", "readable" than the other ones, I guess I was wrong since this JoinableTaskFactory is very VS specific. There should be a recommended way of invoking tasks from a non async method, something that has the benefits of JoinableTaskFactory. Probably JoinableTaskFactory comes with problems also, but that's what I'm trying to understand here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am copy-pasting [a comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27510#issuecomment-473535054) by Andrew Arnott, from a loosely related [GiHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27510). It might give you an idea about why the [`JoinableTaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.joinabletaskfactory) class exists.

> Consider a value factory that needs the UI thread to complete. It is invoked through `AsyncLazy<T>.GetValueAsync` (on an arbitrary thread). Now before the value factory is able to reach the UI thread (even if it started on the UI thread, but yielded before needing it), the UI thread decides to block until some async operation is completed, If that async operation will only complete after the value factory completes, then the value factory must be allowed onto the UI thread to avoid a deadlock. This requires some careful dependency tracking for whatever is blocking the UI thread to know which work it needs to allow in to avoid a deadlock, but also avoid letting unrelated work in which can cause crashes, hangs, data corruption, etc. This is what the `JoinableTaskFactory` is all about, and why we need an `AsyncLazy<T>` that is `JoinableTaskFactory`-aware in order to play by the rules and avoid such problems.

Also from [another comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27510#issuecomment-473429731):

> > The problem with vs-threading is that it's VS specific.
>
> Why do you say that? The entire vs-threading library is completely independent of VS and it will always be so. It targets .NET Standard as well, and we run tests on all operating systems on both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

<sub>**Opinion:** If you want to know my personal perception about the `JoinableTaskFactory`, is that it's an obscure class that is intended to solve an obscure problem, and most likely it's not going to become popular any time soon, if ever.</sub>

Comment: "Popular?"  Is that really a factor?  There are plenty of things like `Span<T>` that are only used under rather specific circumstances.  Their lack of popularity doesn't make them any less useful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "popular" might not be the correct wording. To me the `JoinableTaskFactory` looks more like a solution asking for a problem, than the other way around. I've never seen a question in StackOverflow, where the accepted answer involved a `JoinableTaskFactory`. Instead I've seen a couple of questions, like this one, where the `JoinableTaskFactory` was the question, not the answer. So by "popular" I mean "widely perceived as something useful". That's my prediction, and I might be proven wrong.